# Retrieve a PDF file in VARBINARY(MAX) from a SQL SERVER database from a PHP query

Tags: php, sql-server

I have PDF documents saved in my database in `varbinary(max)` format, I need to retrieve these files to send them to an android application in byte array format and the request goes through a PHP API.
The data directly in `varbinary`, does not pass, the document is always null

I tried to transfer the data in `varchar(max)`, it works fine, but there are a problems
The  problem  is that to convert it to byte array on application, the transformation takes too much time, I have 45 page total, and it takes 20 minutes with the Kotlin formula - `BigInteger(PermitDocument!!,16).toByteArray()`
the conversion of the PDF
`CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),pd.PermitDocument,1) AS PermitDocument`
my request via my API in PHP:

```
public function GetResultsFromQuery($query,$parameter = null){
        $this->OpenConnection();        
        if(isset($parameter)){
            $statement = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $query, $parameter);
        }else{
            $statement = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $query);
        }       
        if (!$statement) {
            $this->errorConnection = sqlsrv_errors();
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            $this->CloseConnection();
            return null;
        }else{
            $results = array();
            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($statement, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $results[] = $row;
            }
            $this->CloseConnection();
            return $results;
        }       
    }
```

if someone has a solution, it will be welcome.

Comment: If the file were to be written to disk as a normal PDF, how many bytes would it be? Do you _need_ to send a file as a byte array, or could you "somehow" send a link instead, and allow the consuming application to natively download it? There's ways to make links/files transient so that they expire after a certain amount of time. How is the data stored in the database, as base64 or as a string?

Comment: Storing big files in a database is not a good idea to start with. What you normally do is store files as files and then only store their location in the database.

Comment: What really stinks about storing them in the database like that is that in order to stream it you have to pull the data out of the database, then you have to materialize it as a file in the file system. Then you can convert it to a byte array to stream it.

Comment: Storing large blobs of data in a databases is problematic for reasons like this, eg: trying to actually get huge amounts of data in and out efficiently. The general advice is to store the actual file contents in the filesystem, cloud bucket, CDN, etc, and then only store the _location_ of the file in the DB itself.

Comment: That said, MS has an article about streaming LOB content from a result set using [`sqlsrv_get_field()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-get-field.php): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-binary-data-as-a-stream-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver16 and there are [similar methods for PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php) as well.

Comment: As well, what other languages might call "byte arrays" or "binary strings" PHP just calls "strings", so you should not have to re-encode anything.

Comment: The data is saved in hex in a varbinary(max) column.
the length of the file in test in hex is 274459 or 548910 characters

Comment: Have you tried just base64 encoding it in the API, and then decoding that in the Android app? That's a pretty much universal standard for sending binary data.

Comment: I understand that for a website the method is not recommended, I myself in this case, I save in a file and keep only the path in the database. Basically we have a WPF program in c# and all our documents are saved this way for more than 10 years, it works very well.
Even with our android application we save documents regularly without any problem. This new section is causing me problems. I will look into the possibility of creating the PDF file in a folder on the server and send the link to the application for downloading.
Thank you for your comments they are welcome.

Comment: I will also try the base64 encoding in PHP.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks to all, the solution works well with base64_encode on my PHP API and the Base64.getDecoder().decode(PermitDocument) on android with Kotlin